# Makefile Error "File exists" when make -j2

Tags: compiler-errors, makefile

Whenever I use just "make" to compile, my Makefile works fine. But when I use "make -j2", I get the error that

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `objects': File exists
make: *** [objects/robot_driver_agent.o] Error 1
```

This is the Makefile -

```
INCLUDE = -I/usr/include/X11 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/FL/images -I/usr/include/freetype2

CC=g++ 
CFLAGS=-w -D LINUX -O3 -fpermissive 
OBJDIR=objects
SRCDIR=src

LDFLAGS= -L/usr/X11R6/lib$(LIBSELECT) -lpthread -lfltk -lXext -lXft -lfontconfig -lXinerama -lpthread -ldl -lm -lX11

SOURCES_RAW= robot_driver_agent.cpp robot_driver_position.cpp robot_driver_priorityqueue.cpp main.cpp robot_driver_tree.cpp robot_driver_stack.cpp robot_driver_grid.cpp robot_driver_path.cpp grid_analyzer.cpp tcpserver.cpp tcpclient.cpp servercontrol.cpp clientcontrol.cpp robot.cpp udpserver.cpp udpclient.cpp owncontrol.cpp guiwindow.cpp rs232.cpp

TARGET:= go
TARGETD:= go_d

OBJECTS:=$(SOURCES_RAW:.cpp=.o)
OBJECTS:=$(patsubst %.o, $(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(OBJECTS))

SOURCES:=$(SOURCES_RAW)
SOURCES:=$(patsubst %.cpp, $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp, $(SOURCES))

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -w -D LINUX $(INCLUDE) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: src/%.cpp
    test -d $(OBJDIR) || mkdir $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) -g -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@ 

debug: $(TARGETD)

$(TARGETD): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -w -D LINUX $(INCLUDE) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c -g $< $(CFLAGS)-o $@



.PHONY : clean
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJDIR)/*.o
    rm -f $(TARGET) $(TARGETD)
```

Can anyone tell me why using both of the processors with -j2 makes this error appear and how to fix it? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create directories like that; it's a race condition waiting to happen.  Let Make handle the dependency resolution for you:

```
 $(OBJECTS): | $(OBJDIR)

 $(OBJDIR):
         mkdir $(OBJDIR)
```

This is taken directly from the [**order-only prerequisite example**](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) in the Make manual.

Comment: This does work, but each time I compile a file I get "mkdir objects
mkdir: cannot create directory `objects': File exists". How do I get around this?

Comment: @Sterling: You shouldn't get that message.  Can you create a minimal test-case? (i.e. a much simpler makefile).

Comment: Oh its because I had mkdir in two targets. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `mkdir -p`.  It is idempotent (no problems if executed twice with the same argument, or even in parallel). **And** it makes all of the directories if you give a path name with multiple components.

Look at my Makefile here: http://www.kylheku.com/cgit/txr/tree/Makefile

Several instances of `mkdir -p`. Of course, I do see multiple `mkdir -p` jobs being issued when I run make -j, but it isn't a problem.

Another idea is to add the `-` on the mkdir command. (Just like what is used with `rm` in `clean` target rules). But that ignores a genuine error, not only `EEXIST`.

P.S. logic like `if directory does not exist, then mkdir ...` won't work because it has a race condition. The directory might not exist at the time the `if` is evaluated, but then by the time the `mkdir` is evaluated, it suddenly exists. In parallel make, you have to worry about races because writing rules for parallel make is a form of concurrent programming.

Comment: Also, in Makefiles past, I have done this by treating a directory as an explicit dependency with a rule to create it. This will correctly parallelize: `make` will build the directory and then dispatch the parallel rules which depend on it.